# Xcode 6.1 replace greyed out / not available

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to use find / replace in Xcode to replace some deprecated functions however it seems to be greyed out for some reason. I'm still finding my way round Xcode so it may be for something simple, but I can't find what it's unavailable?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'am using Xcode 6.1, find&replace working fine for me. You just type the replace text and press **return key**

When you open, it appears to be greyed out

[image]

Press return key after entering text

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply but unfortunately that's not it. It's still greyed out with something in the replace box. As per here: http://imgur.com/tzA0JIX

Comment: Have tried by pressing `return` key after entering text

Comment: thanks You are right. You have to hit return this it displays the list to be replaced, then replace all can be used.  Very simple now I have it.Thanks